# how can immutant be configured to serve ips other than localhost (127.0.0.1)

Tags: clojure, immutant

I'm not sure how to configure my immutant installation to serve webpages

when I do:

```
>> lein immutant run 

>> curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/testing
```

it works, but

```
>> curl http://172.20.10.3:8080/testing
```

which is an alternative ip on my computer does not.

Where can we configure this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ankur is close to correct - Immutant binds to localhost by default, so you need to specify a different bind address with the `-b` option. Specifying `0.0.0.0` will bind to every interface, but you don't pass a port to `-b`. So, the correct invocation would be:

```
lein immutant run -b 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it using:

`lein immutant run -b 0.0.0.0:8080`